# How to run python scripts online?

Tags: python, cron, hosting

I have a simple python script that gets the local weather forecast and sends an email with the data
I want to run this script daily, i found out that cron is used for this purpose but online cron jobs require a url
I wanted to ask how to host my python scripts so that they run online through a url, if possible that is...

Comment: what url? you need a server with python and cron... cron accepts commands, not urls... exactly the same command that you run locally

Comment: @FlashThunder I dont want to host a server just for a simple script like this, i found a website [link](https://www.easycron.com) where the site calls a url

Comment: url is pointing to some server... and on that url is a script that runs some tasks on that server... there is no possibility to do that without it... the same server has to run python script and send email, it's not like you can do that in the air... sorry for disappointment, but that's a basic knowledge about how internet works

Comment: Oh, i just wanted wanted to know if there was a service where i could host my python script so that i could call it through cron, guess not lol

Comment: oh ok... it's still a server, but I really doubt that there is a free service that would allow sending emails (pythonanywhere.com won't)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using Heroku with a python buildpack as a starting point. Using the flask library, you can very minimally start a web container and expose the endpoint online which can then be queried from your cron service. Heroku also provides a free account which ideally should fit your need.

As a peek into how easy it is to setup flask, well..

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/cron-me')
def cron_me():
    call_my_function_here()
    return 'Success'
```

.. and you're done ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up a simple Flask app at [www.pythonanywhere.com](http://www.pythonanywhere.com), I think it will do the job for you even with the free account.

EDIT: And for sending e-mails, you can use [Mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/), with the free version you can send e-mails to a small number of addresses that need to be validated from the recipient side (to avoid people using it for spam :-))